# HTML radio and checkbox input combined?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, radio-button

How do you combine a radio and checkbox input? With that I mean when you select the radio button it deselects the checkboxes and when you select a checkbox the radio input gets deselected.

Here's my example input form:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="d[]"> option 1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="d[]"> option 2<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="d[]"> option 3<br/>
<input type="radio" name="d[]"> option 4<br/>
```

Which would look like this

[image: Example render of code.]

Now if I were to select `option 4` I want `option 2` and `option 3` to deselect. How do I as best do this? Is there some easy trick or do I have to include some javascript magic?

Comment: You would need JavaScript.  It's not a good idea for reasons of usability.  Having things behave in a way that users do not expect violates the Principle of Least Astonishment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment

Comment: @BobBrown But it would act as I expect 'cause in my mind radio buttons deselect when you select anything else from the same group. And that is what I want to acomplish here.

Comment: It may act as you expect, but it won't act as your readers expect.  You do not have radio buttons.  You have a combination of checkboxes and radio buttons.  Users will not expect that operating a radio button will change any checkbox.  Suggestion: Use all checkboxes and eliminate invalid combinations with JavaScript and an explanatory message.

Comment: @BobBrown So you're saying I should change system? And not use a custom system? I could do that but I thought it would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following ([JQuery](https://jquery.com/) is required). Please also read my comment on OP's accepted answer by @Maxim Orlovsky)

```js
$('input[name="d[]"]').on('change', function(){
    if ($(this).attr('type') == 'radio' ) {
        if ( $(this).prop('checked') ) {
            $('input[name="d[]"][type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
        }
    }
    else {
        if ( $(this).prop('checked') ) {
            $('input[name="d[]"][type="radio"]').prop('checked', false);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="d[]"> option 1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="d[]"> option 2<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="d[]"> option 3<br/>
<input type="radio" name="d[]"> option 4<br/>
```

Comment: IMO the MaximOrlovsky's answer is bugged (if you select option 2, then option 3 and then deselect option 2, the option 4 is automatically selected by itself). However ira's solution is the best answer to akaJag's question.

Answer (score 2):

You need some JavaScript (jQuery):

```
$('input[name="d[]"]').on('change', function(){
    if ($(this).attr('type') == 'radio' ) {
        if ( $(this).prop('checked') ) {
            $('input[name="d[]"][type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
        }else {
            $('input[name="d[]"][type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
        }
    }
    else {
        if ( $(this).prop('checked') ) {
            $('input[name="d[]"][type="radio"]').prop('checked', false);
        }else {
            $('input[name="d[]"][type="radio"]').prop('checked', true);
        }
    }
});
```

Live demo -- http://jsfiddle.net/u2n8j5r2/1/

Comment: That's actually jQuery, so OP would need to include jQuery in his page.  Also, with your fiddle, I can pick Option 4, then go *back* and select options 2 and 3.

Comment: This doesn't deselect the radio button when I select a checkbox. Sorry for being unclear and thanks for quick respond.

Comment: @akaJag : I updated my code, now it works fine -- http://jsfiddle.net/u2n8j5r2/1/.

Comment: @MaximOrlovsky Works nicely! Thanks again for quick respond! I am not certain though if I should use this now concidering it may confuse some users.

Comment: @Maxim Orlovsky Please do check your code again... Looks like something you are missing. For example, if you select option 2, then option 3 and then deselect option 2,  the option 4 is automatically selected by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that uses all checkboxes, does not require jQuery, and should do what you want.  (I've edited the code to change when the error message is removed.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Checkboxes</title>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function chkBoxes() {
    var msg = document.getElementById("msg");
        cb1 = document.getElementById("cb1"),
        cb2 = document.getElementById("cb2"),
        cb3 = document.getElementById("cb3"),
        cb4 = document.getElementById("cb4");

    if (cb4.checked) {
        if (cb1.checked || cb2.checked || cb3.checked) {
            msg.innerHTML = "Option 4 not allowed with options 1-3";
            cb1.checked = false;
            cb2.checked = false;
            cb3.checked = false;
        } 
    } else {
        msg.innerHTML = "";
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" name="d[]" id="cb1" value="1" onchange="chkBoxes();"> option 1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="d[]" id="cb2" value="2" onchange="chkBoxes();"> option 2<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="d[]" id="cb3" value="3" onchange="chkBoxes();"> option 3<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="d[]" id="cb4" value="4" onchange="chkBoxes();"> option 4<br/>
<p id="msg"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok yea I like your answer but I like Maxim's version more 'cause it works if they got the same `name`. And I think yours makes it so you can't select checkbox 1-3 when 4 is selected. I wanted the 4th option to be a radio just so you can't unselect it except by selecting checkbox 1-3